# Binding ip address to urllib2 is not working for me

Tags: python, binding, urllib2, tor

I am newb to urllib2. I tried binding ip address to URL request using urllib2,it does not works for ip address given by tor.

```
import socks
import socket
import urllib2

true_socket = socket.socket


def make_bound_socket(source_ip):
    def bound_socket(*a, **k):
        sock = true_socket(*a, **k)
        sock.bind((source_ip, 0))
        return sock
    return bound_socket

if __name__ == '__main__':
socket.socket = make_bound_socket('123.108.224.70')
print "IP address: from tor-",urllib2.urlopen('http://my-ip.herokuapp.com').read()
```

The ip address above i mention get it form **tor**.Thanks in advanced

It gives me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socks_ppp.py", line 56, in <module>
    newIdentity()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking to bind to the interface corresponding with IP address `123.108.224.70`. If there is no corresponding interface on your machine, then the socket can't be bound, and you'll see an error. Here is a simplified example:

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket()
>>> s.bind(('123.108.224.70', 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

This fails because I have no interface with that IP address and I suspect the same for you - try it out.

You can see what IP addresses correspond to an interface using `ifconfig`. I suspect that `123.108.224.70` is not there.

Otherwise, when I use an IP address that exists on my machine, I find that your code works OK.

Comment: ya you are write.But is there any method to bind such ip if we dont have interface with that ip address.I mean how tor makes it possible to do such call.

Comment: the answer is no